# Convert void (*)() to void (*)(unsigned char)

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I'm trying to convert a `void (*)()` to `void (*)(unsigned char)` but my knowledge in C++ isn't good enough. I searched, but I could not find any examples. So I thought to create a function of function but I get some error:

```
typedef void (* voidFuncPtr)();
void castHandler(voidFuncPtr handler)(uint8_t gpio_num)
{
    handler();
}

void attachInterrupt(uint8_t pin, voidFuncPtr handler, int mode)
{
    // typedef void (* voidFuncPtr)();
    // typedef void (* gpio_interrupt_handler_t)(uint8_t gpio_num);
    // typedef void (* gpio_interrupt_handler_t)(unsigned char)
    gpio_set_interrupt(pin, GPIO_INTTYPE_EDGE_ANY, castHandler(handler));
}
```

> error: 'castHandler' declared as function returning a function  void
>   castHandler(voidFuncPtr handler)(uint8_t gpio_num)
>
> error: 'castHandler' was not declared in this scope
>        gpio_set_interrupt(pin, GPIO_INTTYPE_EDGE_ANY, castHandler(handler));

Can someone help me?

Comment: Which type `gpio_set_interrupt` is expecting? Anyway your `castHandler` is not defined properly. I don't even understand what it is doing at all.

Comment: @EugeneSh. typedef void (* gpio_interrupt_handler_t)(unsigned char)

Comment: Then just make a wrapper taking some dummy `char` and calling your `handler`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. could you give me an example? it would be really great :-)

Comment: `void castHandler(unsigned char dummy) { handler(); }`

Comment: What version of C++ are you using?

Comment: Improve clarity.  Use either one of `unsigned char` or `uint8_t`.

Comment: @AndyG I am using xtensa-lx106-elf-c++ --version
xtensa-lx106-elf-c++ (crosstool-NG crosstool-ng-1.22.0-60-g37b07f6f) 4.8.5

Comment: @chux I am not sure but I thing uint8_t and unsigned char is the same or ?

Comment: @Alexandre Not necessarily.

Comment: @Alexandre When the optional type `uint8_t` exist, it is the same as `unsigned char`.  To use both,  their textual difference unnecessarily adds distraction to the key issues.

Comment: @Alexandre To make things clearer, is the problem that the callback for gpio_set_interrupt is called with an integer parameter but your handler takes no parameters or is it the other way around ??

Comment: @Johan yes you got it: gpio_set_interrupt is called with an integer parameter but your handler takes no parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to maintain a table of handlers for each GPIO. Something like the following (untested and incomplete - some initializations and error checking are omitted) code:

```
typedef void (* voidFuncPtr)();

voidFuncPtr handlers[MAX_HANDLERS];

void attachInterrupt(uint8_t pin, voidFuncPtr handler, int mode)
{
    handlers[pin] = handler;
}

void handleGPIO(unsigned char pin)
{
    if (handlers[pin])
        handlers[pin]();
}

void enableGPIOInterrupts(void)
{
    /// Do this for each available pin
    gpio_set_interrupt(pin, GPIO_INTTYPE_EDGE_ANY, handleGPIO);
}
```

Comment: This seem awesome :D I will try

Comment: Perhaps testing `pin` has an entry in the array needs to be checked

Comment: @EdHeal Added it before the comment :)

Comment: 1. You have not initialised handlers. 2. You need to check `pin < MAX_HANDLERS`

Comment: @EdHeal It is incomplete as said. Just to give the general method. Also I see interrupts are not set properly - something to fix in the answer....

Comment: Should `MAX_HANDLERS` be 256?

Comment: @EdHeal Maybe less.. Depends on the number of GPIOs, probably

Comment: It is actually 16 in this case.

Comment: So pin is in the range 0..15

Answer (score 0):

Why not just write a function to do a redirection i.e.

```
void redirectFunction(unsigned char)
{
   handler();
}
```

then

```
gpio_set_interrupt(pin, GPIO_INTTYPE_EDGE_ANY,redirectFunction);
```

**EDIT**

Perhaps this in C++:

```
void redirectFunction(std::function<void()> handler, unsigned char)
{
   handler();
}

void wibble() { }

gpio_set_interrupt(pin, GPIO_INTTYPE_EDGE_ANY, 
   std::bind(redirectFunction, _1, wibble)

);
```

Comment: I think the function handler points to should be determined at runtime.

Comment: but how should I pass handler to the redirect function?

Comment: Why would you need to? Is it actually different for each call or it is some fixed function?

Comment: it is different for each call. https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/external-interrupts/attachinterrupt/ I am porting an arduino library to esp-open-rtos...

Comment: In this case you will have to maintain a *table* of handlers (global one) and decide which one to call based on the parameter (it is the pin number, right?).

Comment: @EugeneSh. yes this would make sense. There is one handler per pin (more or less but yes an handler belong to a pin)